# Abaqus strain depedent damping and stiffness

Tags: dependencies, abaqus

I want to model an equivalent linear soil meterial in Abaqus, which has strain dependent stiffness and damping.
The damping due to a stead state analysis, it is better to be of type structural.

How can I implement  the dependency of stiffness and damping on strain?

1. With a UMAT?
2. With dependencies? (But I suppose this is not solution dependent)
3. Other suggestions?

However, I do not know if although properly implemented if it can run with steady state analysis. If someone has an example of soultion dependent material properties it would be also a great help.

Comment: UMAT is the way to go.  It's the only way to communicate your special requirements to Abaqus and feed them back into the system.  I'd recommend that you add the finite element tag to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer refers only to Explicit calculation and not implicit.

I am posting the answer from an external link:
http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/programs/fe/abaqus/faq68/abaqusf11.html

*"In the material properties under the keyword *MATERIAL for *ELASTIC specify the range of values of E and the corresponding shear strain values in the ascending order. Here use the deviatoric shear strain values as Field variable 1.*
*MATERIAL, NAME=SHEARDEPEND
*ELASTIC, DEPENDENCIES=1
  1.2E5,  0.3, , 0.0001
  1.5E5,  0.3, , 0.0010
  2.0E5,  0.3, , 0.002
The DEPENDENCIES parameter specifies how many field variables are being used. For this example it is 1.
Note that omitted value is the temperature. Now using user subroutine FIELD specify the Field variable value to be the calculated deviatoric shear strain value."*

From Abaqus Manual:

*DEPENDENCIES
This parameter applies **only to Abaqus/Explicit** analyses when ALPHA=TABULAR and/or BETA=TABULAR.*

So this can be done directly (without an UMAT) for the shear modulus (G is a function of E). The difficult part is the damping. Abaqus allows only for Rayleigh Damping and only for Explicit analysis a dependent damping.